# Editing Protected Worksheet From Another VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on a sign in book using Excel, coding with VBA. I have one tab with the form to type your information, another for the details to be stored upon login, and another to search for a logged user. I have protected Sheet1(Login), and need Sheet2(Log Book) to be protected as well.

**The Issue** The issue is that on Sheet2(Log Book) I want the VBA to be able to add the user's information in the next available row, while having it protected so nobody can go through and change others information. The following is the failed code which I have tried:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Open()
    Worksheet.Protect "Password", UserInterfaceOnly:=True
End Sub

wksht unportect()/wksht protect()
```

Neither of these were working. How else might I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define which worksheet you want to protect. In the example below I have set the object variable `WrkSht` to contain the worksheet properties of the sheet "Log Book". You can protect the sheet by using the protect-method on this object variable.

```
Sub ProtectWorksheet()
    Dim WrkSht As Worksheet
    Set WrkSht = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Log Book")

    WrkSht.Protect Password:="password", UserInterfaceOnly:=True
End Sub
```

Comment: Where should I put this, as a separate Sub (ProtectWorksheet), or in the Code I am trying to access the locked sheet with?